# Git Bash on Windows with Ruby: Waiting for gets() input before printing prompt?

Tags: ruby, windows, git-bash

I'm new to programming/Ruby and can't figure out this quirky issue...

Running this Ruby code through Git Bash on Windows:

**$ ruby test.rb**

```
puts "Give me input: "
input = gets
puts "You gave me #{input}"
```

does not print the "Give me input: " string before waiting for input with gets() as it should. Instead it immediately waits for input before printing the prompt and the result. I've tried using $stdout.flush after the prompt puts() but the output remains the same.

Every other terminal I've used works fine though.

Comment: Try `STDOUT.flush` before `input = gets` or `STDOUT.sync = true` at the begining of the program.

Answer (score 0):

As @user11659763 noted, setting `STDOUT.sync = true` fixes the output so that it is always flushed after each call to `puts` or `print`, as is desired, in Git Bash.